# Lightning Map Marker Color

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-base-component

I'm using lightning:map base component. Is there anyway to make this marker blue?

[image]

Comment: you probably found the solution.. if you haven't, you can use the mapIcon to customize the marker.
mapIcon: {
   path: "[you can find example path at salesforce.com or google map docs]",
   fillColor: marker.IsMatched ? "green" : "red",
   fillOpacity: 0.9,
   strokeWeight: 0,
   rotation: 0,
   scale: 1.5,
   anchor: {x: 15, y: 30}
}

Answer (score 7):

While,  it is not possible to change the color of the original marker, there is one workaround, and that is to use a custom marker, which accepts **path** (shape) of the **mapIcon** similar to the original one. The main difference is that **black dot** inside the marker is missing. I am attaching the option to dynamically change the color according to the different type.

End result would look something like this.

[image: Custom marker workaround]

```
 setMapMarkers(){
    let mapMarkers = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.lstItems.length; i++){
        let item = this.lstItems[i];
        mapMarkers.push({
            
            location: {
                Latitude: item.latitude,
                Longitude:  item.longitude,

            },
            title: item.name,
            value: item.id,
            icon: 'utility:account',
            description: 'Description'
            value: item.id,
            mapIcon: {
                path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
                fillColor: this.getFillColor(item),
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: '#000',
                strokeWeight: 1,
                scale: 1
                // anchor: { x: 15, y: 30 }
            }
        
        });

    }
    this.mapMarkers = mapMarkers;
}
getFillColor(item){
    // default color white
    let res = '#FFFFFF';
    if(item.type === 'myType'){
        let res = '#0000FF'; // blue
    }
    return res;
}
```