# How to change the lightning-map marker icon to current object icon?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, lightning-map

I am trying to change the default red map marker in the `lightning-map` using `mapIcon` property of `mapMarkers`. What I want is to get the current object's icon and show it as map marker.

PS - I am able to get the object icon in .png format, but `mapIcon` does'nt support it.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** possible to change the marker to an icon. Though, what can be done is to specify the **path** (shape) of the mapIcon which then provides possibility of slightly changing shapes and colors of the marker.

For more information about changing the colors and shapes, please refer to this question:

[Lightning Map Marker Color](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305417/lightning-map-marker-color/392920#392920)